# Conditional serialization over each item of a List

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, conditional-statements

I would like to control Xml serialization over each item of a List, suppose you have this :

```
public class Item { 
        [XmlElement("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    #region Conditional serialization
        public bool ShouldSerializeLabel()
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Label);
        }
    #endregion
}

public class Root {
    [XmlArray("items")]
    [XmlArrayItem("item")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    #region Conditional serialization
    // Suppose I have two items but one has no label, 
    // How to avoid this :
    // <items>
    //   <item>
    //     <id>5</id>
    //     <label>5</label>
    //   </item>
    //   <item> // I don't want items without label in my collection, how to tell the XmlSerializer not to serialize them
    //     <id>4</id>
    //   </item>
    // </items>
    //
    // But I still want to have to possibility to do that :
    // <product>
    //  <item> // this item has no label and it's ok
    //    <id>42</id>
    //  </item>
    //  <price>1.99</price>
    // </product>
    #endregion
}
```

How to tell that an Item with string.IsNullOrEmpty(Label)
should not be serialized in my collection ? My workaround is to clean the list of Item before Serializing, but is there a way to do this declaratively ?

Comment: You should look into implementing IXmlSerializable on your class and do custom serialization/deserialization in order to skip the item. There's not conditional attribute in the language for the XmlSerializer which will do this.

Another option is to loop over your item collection and omit the items with an empty label.

Comment: Your second option is my current workaround :)

Answer (score 0):

Write your own xml serializer.  You could use the interface IXmlSerializable
 or you could just write your own ToXml method which outputs a string.  There are many ways to do it but writing your own will give you what you want.

Comment: You're right at some point. I added this :         
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Label))
  {
    writer.WriteElementString("id", Id);
    writer.WriteElementString("label", Label);
  }
}
though it works for my collection, it also means that a single Item that has no label won't serialize anymore. Thus using the IXmlSerializable has a global impact, which I don't want.

Comment: Moreover, the collection render an empty <item/> node :'(